# How correctly to make a condition for rewritecond?

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect from the address

```
site.com/get/g/(.*)/
```

on

```
site.com/country/(.*)/
```

But provided that after `(. *)` There is nothing. That is, if the link is of type:

```
site.com/get/g/(.)/f/(.)
```

then do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^get/g/([^/]+)/?$ /country/$1/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

`[^/]+` matches 1+ characters that are not `/`